# How to return a file with data on a Get request?

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I have an object with data.
I want to return this on a get request.

```
  @Get()
  getHello(@Response() res) {

    const data = {
      firstName: 'Jack',
      lastName:  'Ivanov'
    }

    return res
      .setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/json')
      .setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename="123.json"')
      .write(data)
      .end();
  }
```

Now, I problem with set headers: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Comment: I don't have the file. I want to load data on the get request like a file on client.

Answer (score 0):

For fix this problem - use attachment.

```
@Controller('file')
export class FileController {
    @Get('/')
    @Header('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream')
    @Header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="123.json"')
    getFile() {
        return {
            name: 'Jack'
        }
    }
}
```